# I am moving selected data from one listbox to another but I am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#

```
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;////(error occured here)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item.Text);
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(item.Text);
            string usrid = null;

            string usridselect = "select user_id from user_membership where email_id ='" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection sqcon = DBConnection.connectDB();
            sqcon.Open();

            SqlDataReader sqldr = DBConnection.SelectData(usridselect, sqcon);
            if (sqldr.HasRows)
            {
                while (sqldr.Read())
                {
                    usrid = sqldr[0].ToString();
                }
            }
            sqldr.Close();
```

Comment: Please clarify. Where does the error occur (which line)? If you get that error, you can jump to the line where the error occured and then you will most probably see which object is null.

Comment: Please give us more information, what line is the error originating from ?

Comment: Does the binding of the items to the listbox happen in a !IsPostback? If not then your SelectedItem will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your comment... Try to check if selectedItem != null

```
  if (ListBox1.SelectedItem!=null)
  {
       /// paste your code here

       /// anyway - keep in mind that you refer to a selectedItem in your listbox after
       /// you removed it from the according listbox
  }
```

Comment: it is not working .it is showing the same error..I am using it under a button control.

Comment: could you paste the complete eventHandler code pls! and the exact error information

Comment: protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string email_id = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;///(showing error here)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(email_id);
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(email_id);
            string usrid = null;

            string usridselect = "select user_id from user_membership where email_id ='" + email_id + "'";
            SqlConnection sqcon = DBConnection.connectDB();
            sqcon.Open();

Comment: I just don't get it... You are sure, that ListBox1 is a pointer to an object of type Listbox? you may check this by: if (ListBox1==null) { /// listBox1 is a NULL pointer } else { /// here goes my previous code }